# Sorting based on hour and weekday?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a `list` of `dict`s like this, which I want to sort as shown below:

```
[{'07 PM': [{'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0},
            {'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0}]},
 {'08 PM': [{'Saturday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Sunday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0}]},
 {'05 PM': [{'Saturday': 0},
            {'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0}]},
 {'09 PM': [{'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Sunday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0}]},
```

***Desired output:***

```
[{'01 AM': [{'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0},
            ]},
 {'02 AM': [{'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0},
            ]},
 {'03 AM': [{'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0},
            ]},
]
```

That is I want it sorted by hour (24 hour format) and also by weekdays. Sorting lexographically would not work out in this case, so I tried passing a `key` parameter to `sorted()`, where `key` was in the correct order that I wanted:

```
sorted(my_unsorted_data, key=sorted_data.index)
```

where `sorted_data` was the desired output above, but got this error:

`{'07 PM': [{'Tuesday': 0}, {'Saturday': 0}, {'Sunday': 0}, {'Monday': 0}, {'Thursday': 0}, {'Wednesday': 0}, {'Friday': 0}]} is not in list`.

Comment: Which code did you try, exactly?

Comment: @EricDuminil  `sorted(my_unsorted_data,key=sorted_data.index)` where `sorted_data` is the above expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer dictionaries in your lists only have one key each in the format of a number followed by `'AM'` or `'PM`. To sort the outer dictionaries, we can define the sort-key

```
def sortouter(dic):
    hour_str = dic.keys()[0] # list(dic.keys())[0] in Python 3
    hour, am_pm = hour_str.split()
    return (am_pm, int(hour))
```

Assuming your list is named `dicts`, apply by issueing

```
dicts.sort(key=sortouter)
```

This will sort by `'AM'`/`'PM'` first (coincidally, 'AM' comes before 'PM' lexicographically) and by numeric value of the hour second.

In order to sort each inner list, loop over your list of dictionaries and sort each of these lists by the only key (the weekday) they have. Of course, we need another sortkey to order the weekdays.

```
def sortinner(dic):
    day = dic.keys()[0] # Python 3: list(dic.keys())[0]        
    return {'Sunday': 0, 'Monday': 1, ..., 'Saturday': 7}[day]
```

The loop:

```
for dic in dicts:
    for lst in dic.values(): # only one iteration with your current format
        lst.sort(key=sortinner)
```

> your solution works can you please explain how sortouter works in little more detail

When you call `dicts.sort(key=sortouter)` the dictionaries in the list `dicts` get passed to `sortouter` (parameter named `dic`).

The first line of the function simply gets the only key in each of the dictionaries in `dicts`, for example `'02 AM'`.

The second line splits the string by the blank and  - sticking to the example - assigns `'02'` to the name `hour` and `'AM'` to the name `am_pm`.

Finally the sort-key that is returned is the tuple `('AM', 2)`.

Now, Python will sort the list of dictionaries *as if* it was a list of (AM/PM, integer) tuples (sorting something as if it looked like something else is the whole idea behind a sort-key).

Tuples are sorted lexicographically like strings, i.e. for two tuples `t` and `s` the tuple `t` is smaller than `s` if `t[0] < s[0]`. If `t[0] == s[0]` then the next elements, `t[1]` and `s[1]` are compared, and so on.

Thus, since `'AM'` < `'PM'` (because `'A'` < '`P`') all `'AM'`-dicts come before the `'PM'`-dicts (Python does not even have to look at the integer in the return value of `sortouter` to make that decision). Within the group of either all `'AM'`- or `'PM'`-dicts, the second element of the tuple `sortouter` returns gets compared (since the first element is the same), so the dictionaries get sorted by ascending hour.

Comment: your solution works can you please explain how `sortouter` works in little more detail

Comment: @anekix I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: @timgeb: The effort for the answer should be proportional to the effort put in the question. Your explanation is very good, but it might be overkill IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

## Sort weekdays

In order to sort your list of dicts with weekdays, you could define a dict with week days as keys and id as values :

```
wday_numbers = {
    'Sunday': 0,
    'Monday': 1,
    'Tuesday': 2,
    'Wednesday': 3,
    'Thursday': 4,
    'Friday': 5,
    'Saturday': 6
}


dicts = [{'Tuesday': 0},
         {'Saturday': 0},
         {'Monday': 0},
         {'Sunday': 0},
         {'Thursday': 0},
         {'Friday': 0},
         {'Wednesday': 0}]

print(sorted(dicts, key=lambda x: wday_numbers[list(x.keys())[0]]))
# [{'Sunday': 0}, {'Monday': 0}, {'Tuesday': 0}, {'Wednesday': 0}, {'Thursday': 0}, {'Friday': 0}, {'Saturday': 0}]
```

## Sort times

You could write a helper function which converts `03 AM` to `3` and `2 PM` to `14` :

```
def to_24h(hour_pm_am):
    hour, pm_am = hour_pm_am.split(' ')
    if pm_am == "PM":
        return int(hour)+12
    else:
        return int(hour)

print(sorted(['07 PM', '08 AM', '03 PM', '03 AM'], key=to_24h))
# ['03 AM', '08 AM', '03 PM', '07 PM']
```

## Note

It's usually not a good idea to have a list of dicts with single, unique values. This list of dicts could be converted to one dict (if the order is important, to an OrderedDict).

You'll get the exact same information, but it will be much easier to retrieve information.

Here's an example :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

wday_numbers = {
    'Sunday': 0,
    'Monday': 1,
    'Tuesday': 2,
    'Wednesday': 3,
    'Thursday': 4,
    'Friday': 5,
    'Saturday': 6
}

dicts = [{'Tuesday': 9},
         {'Saturday': 3},
         {'Monday': 2},
         {'Sunday': 5},
         {'Thursday': 4},
         {'Friday': 7},
         {'Wednesday': 1}]

pairs = [(day, number) for dct in dicts for day, number in dct.items()]
pairs.sort(key=lambda d: wday_numbers[d[0]])
ordered_days = OrderedDict(pairs)

print(ordered_days)
# OrderedDict([('Sunday', 5), ('Monday', 2), ('Tuesday', 9), ('Wednesday', 1), ('Thursday', 4), ('Friday', 7), ('Saturday', 3)])
```

Comment: how does it know in which order to sort ?

Comment: For every weekday, it checks the corresponding `id` from `wday_numbers`, and uses it as sorting criteria.

Comment: i get this error `dict' object has no attribute 'split'"` when i use this in above data that i mentioned.how can it be done?i have dict of lists so maybe that error

Comment: @anekix: This isn't a complete answer, and it shouldn't be a complete answer IMHO. If you want one, you should prove that you invested time and effort while searching for a solution. My answer does contain the 2 most important parts you'll need, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take.

Sample input data:

```
data = [{'07 PM': [{'Tuesday': 0},
                   {'Saturday': 0},
                   {'Sunday': 0},
                   {'Monday': 0},
                   {'Thursday': 0},
                   {'Wednesday': 0},
                   {'Friday': 0}]},
        {'08 AM': [{'Saturday': 0},
                   {'Tuesday': 0},
                   {'Monday': 0},
                   {'Sunday': 0},
                   {'Thursday': 0},
                   {'Friday': 0},
                   {'Wednesday': 0}]},
        {'05 PM': [{'Saturday': 0},
                   {'Sunday': 0},
                   {'Monday': 0},
                   {'Thursday': 0},
                   {'Tuesday': 0},
                   {'Wednesday': 0},
                   {'Friday': 0}]},
        {'09 PM': [{'Tuesday': 0},
                   {'Saturday': 0},
                   {'Monday': 0},
                   {'Sunday': 0},
                   {'Thursday': 0},
                   {'Friday': 0},
                   {'Wednesday': 0}]},
       ]
```

Code:

```
WEEKDAY_RANK = dict(zip('Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,'
                        'Thursday,Friday,Saturday'.split(','), range(7)))

def time_to_24(time_of_day):
    hour, am_pm = time_of_day.split()
    return int(hour) + (0 if am_pm == 'AM' else 12)

desired = []
for d in sorted(data, key=lambda d: time_to_24( d.items()[0][0] )):
    time_of_day, values = d.items()[0]
    values.sort(key=lambda d: WEEKDAY_RANK[ d.items()[0][0] ])
    desired.append({time_of_day: values})

from pprint import pprint
pprint(desired)
```

Output:

```
[{'08 AM': [{'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0}]},
 {'05 PM': [{'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0}]},
 {'07 PM': [{'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0}]},
 {'09 PM': [{'Sunday': 0},
            {'Monday': 0},
            {'Tuesday': 0},
            {'Wednesday': 0},
            {'Thursday': 0},
            {'Friday': 0},
            {'Saturday': 0}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic approach

```
days = {'Sunday':0, 'Monday':1, 'Tuesday':2, 'Wednesday':3, 'Thursday':4, 'Friday':5, 'Saturday':6}

def time_custom(val):
    time = val.keys()[0]
    val[time] = sorted(val[time], key=lambda x: days[x.keys()[0]])
    return time

myList = sorted(myList, key=time_custom )
```